# Exercise in Galois cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a local field, and $\bar{K}$ its algebraic closure. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of (continuous) $G=\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$-modules. 
Let $M$ be a finite $G$-module.
For any injective module $I$ of $\mathcal{C}$,

is $H^r(G, \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,~I))=0$ for all $r>0$?

(Here on $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,~A)$, $g \in G$ acts as $(g\phi)(x)=g(\phi(g^{-1}(x)))$.)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you really considering *all* $G$-modules? No topology involved, just some abelian group with a $G$-action?

Comment: Sorry, I changed a bit. Thank you very much.

Comment: With the new formulation, I would be very surprised if $\mathcal{C}$ had any non-zero injectives.

Comment: Thanks David, I changed again, which seems better than before.

Comment: If this "exercise" (for which no motivation has been given) is now rendered moot due to the answer to your other question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263088/spectral-sequence-of-galois-cohomology-over-local-fields (which seems almost surely to be what the motivation was), perhaps the above question should be edited to reflect that the exercise is no longer of interest to you (if I understand correctly the motivation).